# select child textnode with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to match text `Test number 3` using xpath in selenium.

```
<span>
    <br> Test number 1
    <br> Test number 2
    <br> Test number 3
</span>
```

I can get span element and then get last textnode from list similarly to `/span//text()[3]`

But can I check if Test number 3 exists directly via xpath something like below

```
'//span[contains(text()," Test number 3")]'
```

This doesn't work, only part work is  `'//span[contains(text()," Test")]'`

But can I match with `Test number 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the "contains" check to `.` - a [string value of the `span` node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value), `text()` would just match the first [text node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Text-Nodes) inside the `span`:

```
.//span[contains(normalize-space(.), "Test number 3")]
```

Comment: not sure why but `normalize-space()` worked and not just `.` i.e. `//span[contains(normalize-space(), "Test number 3")]`

Comment: @user2661518: If `//span[contains(., "Test number 3")]` didn't select the span in your example, then (1) your real case is actually different (for example, there could be multiple spaces in between `Test` and `number` that `normalize-space()` is collapsing), (2) you made a mistake in your test, or (3) you're using a broken XPath implementation.